# Python email - 8bit MIME support

Tags: python, email, mime

I'm writing a simple MUA application, and I have a troubles with generating message.

I want to my program automatically detect whether the SMTP server supports `8bit MIME`, and if yes, then it'll generate a message, where the part with plain text will be encoded on 8bits. In MIME header it should looks like that:

`Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit`

The major problem is that, python3.4 smtplib hasn't `8-bit encoder`, just only `base64`, and `quoted printable`

In my case it looks that:

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = 'someone@example.com'
msg['To'] = 'someone@example.com'
msg['Subject'] = 'subject'

text = MIMEText("text here".encode('utf-8'), _charset='utf-8')

msg.attach(text)

# then sending...
```

The `text.as_string()` call returns

```
'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\ndGV4dCBoZXJl\n'
```

This message is quite good, but I'd want to have `8-bit` enconding, not `base64`.

The question is am I really convicted to use `base64` enconding?

In `email.encoders` are only `encode_base64` and `encode_quopri` functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default body encoding for utf-8 is BASE64 which can be replaced locally:

```
    from email import charset
    ch = charset.Charset('utf-8')
    ch.body_encoding = '8bit'
    text = MIMEText("")
    text.set_charset(ch)
    text.set_payload("text here")
    text.replace_header('Content-Transfer-Encoding', '8bit')
    msg.attach(text)
```

or globally:

```
    from email import charset
    charset.add_charset('utf-8', charset.SHORTEST, '8bit')

    text = MIMEText("text here".encode('utf-8'), _charset='utf-8')
    text.replace_header('Content-Transfer-Encoding', '8bit')

    msg.attach(text)
```

Comment: I've battled  to make the first local method work but it simply didn't work, couldn't figure it out.